# altium designer unknown pin error

Tags: altium

I am trying to learn altium.I just placed stm32f407vg microcontroller and one resistor these gives me error as in the picture :

(Failed to add the class and unknown pin error)
http://oi68.tinypic.com/28hzbeu.jpg

Comment: do you have a footprint defined for the resistor?

Comment: yes I am  actually using standary altium Res3

Comment: Probably the footprint is not defined for it. Open **Footprint Manager** window via Tools -> Footprint Manager menu item. In the window, find and select the resistor from the Component List to the left then see if there's a footprint is defined or not.

Answer (score 2):

The resister footprint is not matching with your schematic.In the schematic, the resistor R1 terminals were named like R1-1 and R1-2.But, footprint pads name not 1 and 2.Thats the problem.

Go to the corresponding library and Edit the footprint pad name.Then it will be Okay.